# SQL to find where not exists on one table

Tags: sql, except

I want to find the list of any COMPANYID/USERID combos on the USERS table that does NOT have at least 1 ACCOUNT found on the ACCOUNT table.
In the example below, ABC/USER3 is the only combo that fits this.  The rest of them have at least 1 ACCOUNT that is on the Account table.

TABLE: USERS

| COMPANYID | USERID | ACCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | USER1 | 111 |
| ABC | USER1 | 222 |
| ABC | USER1 | 333 |
| ABC | USER2 | 222 |
| ABC | USER2 | 444 |
| ABC | USER2 | 888 |
| ABC | USER3 | 333 |
| ABC | USER3 | 666 |

TABLE: ACCOUNT

| ACCOUNT |
| --- |
| 111 |
| 222 |
| 444 |
| 555 |
| 777 |

Comment: what have you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for where something does *not exist* in an exclusive list of those that *do* exist; Using the *exists* operator will likely be the most efficient method.

```
select distinct CompanyId, UserId
from users u where not exists (
    select userid
    from users u2
    where exists (select * from account a where a.account = u2.account)
    and u2.userid=u.userid
)
```

Comment: Stu, that seems to work.   (I have over 900K rows on the accounts table and millions of rows on the users table)   I only need the distinct COMPANYID/USERID combo returned once.  How complex does it get adding that?

Answer (score 0):

With a left join, those will be having 0 matching accounts.

```
SELECT USR.COMPANYID, USR.USERID
FROM USERS USR
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT ACC ON ACC.ACCOUNT = USR.ACCOUNT
GROUP BY USR.COMPANYID, USR.USERID
HAVING COUNT(ACC.ACCOUNT) = 0
```